# Seemingly incorrect mocking behaviour using OCMock

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, objective-c-blocks, ocmock

I'm doing something like this in my test

```
- (void)testSomething {
    __block BOOL isActive = NO;
    void (^doSomething)(void) = ^void(void) {
        isActive = YES;
        .....
    }

    [[someMock stub] andDo:^(NSInvocation *invocation) {
        NSValue *returnValue = 
            [NSValue valueWithBytes:&isActive
                           objCType:@encode(BOOL)];
        [invocation setReturnValue:&returnValue];
     }] isSomeMockActive];

     [self.someObject doSomethingWithHandler:doSomething];

     /// === verify ===
}

// Assume isSomeMockActive is a function on some real object

// Function in the real object

- (void)doSomethingWithHandler:(void(^)void)handler {
    // ....
    if ([someMock isSomeMockActive]) {
        // ....
    }  
    handler();
    if ([someMock isSomeMockActive]) {
        // this still returns NO even though handler correctly
        // sets isActive to YES in the tests
    }
    // ....
}
```

What I've observed is when `isSomeMockActive` is hit my `isActive` is correct `NO` and then `YES` but invariably what is being returned by `isSomeMockActive` is always `NO`.

PS: I've tried using `[self.mock stub] andReturnValue:...]` and that seems to be having the same issue.

Is there anything wrong I'm doing?

Comment: what is `isRegistrationClientActive`? what is `isSomeMockActive`? where is something being returned as `NO`?

Comment: Sorry `isRegistrationClientActive` should actually have been `isActive`. Let's imagine `isSomeMockActive` is a method that would be called internally when `doSomethingWithHandler:` is invoked and that should invariably return whatever `isActive` holds at that point of time. Now when my handler (`doSomething`) is invoked it should set `isActive` to YES.

What I'm observing is that it does call `doSomething` which correctly sets `isActive` to `YES` but then if I still call `isSomeMockActive` it correctly sets the `returnValue` to YES but apparently all the Invocation dance makes it return NO.

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a bug in OCMock somewhere. I'm not able to pinpoint where it's wrong though, I'll need to investigate a bit more.

A simpler workaround to this is using selectors to stub methods rather than blocks. So instead of having `isActive` as a local variable you make it an iVar and then you can do

```
 OCMStub([some mockIsSomeMockActive]).andCall(self, @selector(isActive))
```